# Eclipse/pydev can't resolve module

Tags: eclipse, pydev, python-3.6

I'm using PyDev within Eclipse (Oxygen) and have Python 3.6 installed. The Preferences and project properties both show Python 3.6 being used. But when I try to use **calendar**, I get

```
<bound method TextCalendar.formatyear of <calendar.TextCalendar object at 0x1073839e8>>
```

when I print it out. And Eclipse/PyDev can't resolve **calendar**

In **idle3** if I print out **calendar**, it shows that it's coming from Python 3.6,

```
<module 'calendar' from '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/calendar.py'>
```

How do I get this properly configured?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My imports included:

```
from calendar import calendar
```

This is what caused the problem. Changing it to just

```
import calendar
```

got the correct module.